# Reference NSManagedObject entity from inside NSValueTransformer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsvaluetransformer

I'm using NSValueTranformer to encrypt certain Core Data attributes. This all works fine, except I need to be able to use a different encryption key depending on the NSManagedObject. Is there anyway I can access this entity from within my transformer class?

The use case is I have multiple users with different passwords that can access different NSManagedObject entities. If I use the same encryption key for all of the objects, someone could just reassign who owns them in the SQL db and they would still decrypt.

Any ideas on the best way to go about this?

Edit:
I should mention I'm doing this in iOS.

Comment: Can I assume only one user is logged in at a time? can you clear your CoreData stack after sign-out? also, does users share unrestricted data on the same store, or could you open a different store for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third times the charm? Let me see if I can address your only-transform-when-going-to-disk requirement. Think of this as a hybrid of the other two approaches.

```
@interface UserSession : NSObject

+ (UserSession*)currentSession;
+ (void)setCurrentSession: (UserSession*)session;
- (id)initWithUserName: (NSString*)username andEncryptionKey: (NSData*)key;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* userName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSData* encryptionKey;

@end

@implementation UserSession

static UserSession* gCurrentSession = nil;

+ (UserSession*)currentSession
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        return gCurrentSession;
    }
}

+ (void)setCurrentSession: (UserSession*)userSession
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        gCurrentSession = userSession;
    }
}

- (id)initWithUserName: (NSString*)username andEncryptionKey: (NSData*)key
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _userName = [username copy];
        _encryptionKey = [key copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    _userName = nil;
    _encryptionKey = nil;
}

@end

@interface EncryptingValueTransformer : NSValueTransformer
@end

@implementation EncryptingValueTransformer

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{    
    UserSession* session = [UserSession currentSession];
    NSAssert(session, @"No user session! Can't decrypt!");

    NSData* key = session.encryptionKey;
    NSData* decryptedData = Decrypt(value, key);
    return decryptedData;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    UserSession* session = [UserSession currentSession];
    NSAssert(session, @"No user session! Can't encrypt!");

    NSData* key = session.encryptionKey;
    NSData* encryptedData = Encrypt(value, key);
    return encryptedData;
}

@end
```

The only tricky part here is that you have to be sure that the current `UserSession` is set up *before* you create the managed object context and isn't changed until *after* the context is saved and deallocated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't work for me. If a user isn't logged-in the app still has to download information for them and store it, so I can't have a singleton to get the key from. Also, not that I see an issue in this implementation related to it, but the app uses multiple contexts across multiple threads.

Comment: If you're downloading stuff on the user's behalf then storing it, how about putting the key in the `threadDictionary` when you start the save operation, and then pulling it out afterward? Then the value transformer could get to it. This would also allow you to be doing things on behalf of different users on different threads simultaneously.

Comment: Thought about this, but certain threads are shared for users, and the persistence to disk only happens on the main thread. This is driving me crazy, there has to be a way to pass some information to this transformer upon creation.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the CoreData API was not designed with such a use case in mind. I suspect you're going to have to munge your requirements a bit to enable a solution. (i.e. one user per thread, interlock save operations another way (other than marshaling to the main thread), etc.)

Comment: Here's a thought. MD5 hash the string, store it on a singleton with the userID associated with it. From the transformer, ask for the encryption key associated the MD5 hash of the string and encrypt it. Then pass the MD5 hash of the encrypted data to the singleton and associate it with the key. Upon decryption again pass in the md5 hash, only for the encrypted string, and get the decryption key. I think that might actually work......

Comment: Ugh you're right. I can create a new NSManagedObject called EncryptionMapping with both the encrypted and decrypted hashes. And associate it with the object. Then I can look up what object is associated with that encryption mapping.

Comment: In terms of performance, this will be horrible. for each encryption/decription, you must obtain a lock on the session. cache the key, and during session change, close the store.

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is this: You need to write the hash<->hid map AFTER all the transformations take place, which won't be until the save operation is already in flight.  I don't think you'll be able to trust that the updated map is persisted last, which means that every save operation is now TWO save operations. Seriously, just use the derived property approach and cache the results, so the transformation isn't done on every access of the property. The requirement that this only happen at persistence time is what's really killing you here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom instances of `NSValueTransformer` subclasses that have state (i.e. the encryption key) and pass them in to `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` in the options dictionary using the `NSValueTransformerBindingOption` key.

You won't be able to set this up in IB directly since IB references value transformers by class name, but you can do it in code. If you're feeling extra ambitious you can set up the bindings in IB and then replace them with different options in code later.

It might look something like this:

```
@interface EncryptingValueTransformer : NSValueTransformer

@property (nonatomic,readwrite,copy) NSData* encryptionKey;

@end

@implementation EncryptingValueTransformer

- (void)dealloc
{
    _encryptionKey = nil;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    if (!self.encryptionKey)
        return nil;

    // do the transformation

    return value;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    if (!self.encryptionKey)
        return nil;

    // Do the reverse transformation

    return value;
}

@end


@interface MyViewController : NSViewController

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) IBOutlet NSControl* controlBoundToEncryptedValue;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

// Other stuff...

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    // Replace IB's value tansformer binding settings (which will be by class and not instance) with specific,
    // stateful instances.
    for (NSString* binding in [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue exposedBindings])
    {
        NSDictionary* bindingInfo = [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue infoForBinding: binding];
        NSDictionary* options = bindingInfo[NSOptionsKey];
        if ([options[NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption] isEqual: NSStringFromClass([EncryptingValueTransformer class])])
        {
            // Out with the old
            [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue unbind: binding];

            // In with the new
            NSMutableDictionary* mutableOptions = [options mutableCopy];
            mutableOptions[NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption] = nil;
            mutableOptions[NSValueTransformerBindingOption] = [[EncryptingValueTransformer alloc] init];
            [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue bind: binding
                                           toObject: bindingInfo[NSObservedObjectKey]
                                        withKeyPath: bindingInfo[NSObservedKeyPathKey]
                                            options: mutableOptions];
        }
    }
}

// Assuming you're using the standard representedObject pattern, this will get set every time you want
// your view to expose new model data. This is a good place to update the encryption key in the transformers'
// state...

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    for (NSString* binding in [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue exposedBindings])
    {
        id transformer = [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue infoForBinding: NSValueBinding][NSOptionsKey][NSValueTransformerBindingOption];
        EncryptingValueTransformer* encryptingTransformer = [transformer isKindOfClass: [EncryptingValueTransformer class]] ? (EncryptingValueTransformer*)transformer : nil;
        encryptingTransformer.encryptionKey = nil;
    }

    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

    // Get key from model however...
    NSData* encryptionKeySpecificToThisUser = /* Whatever it is... */ nil;

    for (NSString* binding in [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue exposedBindings])
    {
        id transformer = [self.controlBoundToEncryptedValue infoForBinding: NSValueBinding][NSOptionsKey][NSValueTransformerBindingOption];
        EncryptingValueTransformer* encryptingTransformer = [transformer isKindOfClass: [EncryptingValueTransformer class]] ? (EncryptingValueTransformer*)transformer : nil;
        encryptingTransformer.encryptionKey = encryptionKeySpecificToThisUser;
    }
}

// ...Other stuff

@end
```

Comment: It doesn't look like NSValueTransformerBindOption is available on iOS, am I wrong about that?

Comment: Oh yeah... there are no Cocoa bindings at all on iOS. If you're on iOS, then you don't care about the bindings stuff at all. Just make an NSValueTransformer subclass with state, set the state whenever the user changes, and you're done.

Comment: CoreData doesn't have the same facility to supply instances to the managed object model -- only class names. Oh well. That sucks. Given that, my advice would be to just have the property on the managed object vend the encrypted data and then have your code that consumes the objects transform the data as necessary using the right key. I don't think there's a way to do it endogenously without some pretty hacky stuff.

Comment: The issue there is performance. I can only encrypt and decrypt this value when going to or from disk. I guess I will have to try some hacky objc runtime stuff to see If I can somehow make this work.

Comment: I've posted two more answers with two other options, one of which will hopefully be workable for you.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This was bugging me so I thought about it some more... I think the easiest way is to have some sort of "session" object and then have a "derived property" on your managed object. Assuming you have an entity called UserData with a property called `encryptedData`, I whipped up some code that might help illustrate:

```
@interface UserData : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * unencryptedData;
@end

@interface UserData () // Private
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * encryptedData;
@end

// These functions defined elsewhere
NSData* Encrypt(NSData* clearData, NSData* key);
NSData* Decrypt(NSData* cipherData, NSData* key);

@interface UserSession : NSObject

+ (UserSession*)currentSession;

- (id)initWithUserName: (NSString*)username andEncryptionKey: (NSData*)key;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* userName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSData* encryptionKey;

@end

@implementation UserData

@dynamic encryptedData;
@dynamic unencryptedData;

+ (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingUnencryptedData
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(encryptedData))];
}

- (NSData*)unencryptedData
{
    UserSession* session = [UserSession currentSession];
    if (nil == session)
        return nil;

    NSData* key = session.encryptionKey;
    NSData* encryptedData = self.encryptedData;
    NSData* decryptedData = Decrypt(encryptedData, key);
    return decryptedData;
}

- (void)setUnencryptedData:(NSData *)unencryptedData
{
    UserSession* session = [UserSession currentSession];
    NSAssert(session, @"No user session! Can't encrypt!");

    NSData* key = session.encryptionKey;
    NSData* encryptedData = Encrypt(unencryptedData, key);

    self.encryptedData = encryptedData;
}

@end

@implementation UserSession

static UserSession* gCurrentSession = nil;

+ (UserSession*)currentSession
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        return gCurrentSession;
    }
}

+ (void)setCurrentSession: (UserSession*)userSession
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        gCurrentSession = userSession;
    }
}

- (id)initWithUserName: (NSString*)username andEncryptionKey: (NSData*)key
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _userName = [username copy];
        _encryptionKey = [key copy];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    _userName = nil;
    _encryptionKey = nil;
}

@end
```

The idea here is that when a given user logs in you create a new UserSession object and call `+[UserSession setCurrentSession: [[UserSession alloc] initWithUserName: @"foo" andEncryptionKey: <whatever>]]`. The derived property (`unencryptedData`) accessor and mutator get the current session and use the key to transform the values back and forth to the "real" property. (Also, don't skip over the `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingUnencryptedData` method. This tells the runtime about the relationship between the two properties, and will help things work more seamlessly.)

Comment: I see in other comments that you've added the requirement that the transformation only be done at persistence time. I added a third answer that hopes to address that new requirement.